# Addressing a database as a multi-level associative array

Tags: database, associative-array

I'm writing a web game, where it's very convenient to think about the complete game state as a single arbitrary-level hash.

A couple examples of the game state being updated:

```
// Defining a mission card that could be issued to a player
$game['consumables']['missions']['id04536']['name'] = "Build a Galleon for Blackbeard";
$game['consumables']['missions']['id04536']['requirements']['lumber'] = 20;
$game['consumables']['missions']['id04536']['requirements']['iron'] = 10;
$game['consumables']['missions']['id04536']['rewards']['blackbeard_standing'] = 5;

// When a player turns in this mission card with its requirements
$game['players']['id3214']['blackbeard_standing'] += 5;
```

This is a web game, so storing the information in a database makes sense. I need the features of a database: That the game state can be accessed from multiple browsers at the same time, that it's non-volatile and easy to back up, etc.

Essentially, I want syntax as easy as reading-to/writing-from an associative array of arbitrary depth. I need all the functionality of dealing with an associative array: Not just simple reads and writes, the but the ability to run foreach loops against it, and so on. And I need the effect to actually be to perform all reads/writes from a database, not from volatile memory.

I'm personally fond of raw Ruby, but if there's a specific language or framework that gives me this one feature, it would make the rest of this project easy enough to be worth using.

Comment: I've gone ahead and answered anyway, but do you really think you need this?  You're going to end up writing an awful lot of code to *traverse* that structure; code that's already been written for using databases in the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB(+its Ruby gem) was the best answer I found. And so easy to install and learn.

It gets me 90% of the way to treating the entire game state as a multi-level hash. Close enough. I can treat the collections as the first hash level, and use it to store & retrieve multilevel hashes.

Answer (score 1):

any language, framework?  How about python+sqlalchemy+postgresql

- python because you can easily create new types that behave for all the world like regular `dict`s
- postgres because it has two particularly interesting types uncommon in other sql databases, we'll get to that in a moment.
- sqlalchemy because it can do all of the dirty work of dealing with an rdbms concisely.

Using a sql database like this is awkward, because the normal 'key' you would want in a table has to be a fixed set of columns, so ideally, you'd need a single column for the whole "path" into the deeply nested mapping.

An even more irritating problem is that you seem to want to store a range of different types at the leaves.  This is not ideal.

Fortunately, postgres can help us out with both issues, using a `TEXT[]` for the first, we can have a single column so that every entry can concisely represent the whole path, all the way down the tree.  For the second, we can use `JSON`, which is exactly like it sounds, permitting arbitrary json encodable types, which significantly does include both strings and numbers as in your code example.

Because I am lazy, i'll use sqlalchemy to do *most* of the work.  First, we need a table using the above types:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgres as pg

Base = declarative_base()

class AssocStorage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assoc_storage'
    key = Column(pg.ARRAY(pg.TEXT, as_tuple=True), primary_key=True)
    value = Column(pg.JSON)
```

That will give us a relational version of a single entry in a deeply nested mapping.  We're most of the way there already:

```
>>> engine = create_engine('postgres:///database')
>>> Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  ## beware, extreem lazyness
>>> session = Session(bind=engine)    ## also unusually lazy, real applications should use `sessionmaker`
>>> session.add(AssocStorage(key=('foo','bar'), value=5))
>>> session.commit()
>>> x = session.query(AssocStorage).get((('foo', 'bar'),))
>>> x.key
(u'foo', u'bar')
>>> x.value
5
```

Okay, not too bad, but this is a little more annoying to use, Like i mentioned earlier, the python type system is compliant enough to make this look like a normal dict, we need only give a class that implements the proper protocol:

```
import collections
class PersistentDictView(collections.MutableMapping):
    # a "production grade" version should actually implement these:
    __delitem__ = __iter__ = __len__ = NotImplemented

    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.session.query(AssocStorage).get((key, )).value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        existing_item = self.session.query(AssocStorage).get((key, ))
        if existing_item is None:
            existing_item = AssocStorage(key=key)
            self.session.add(existing_item)
        existing_item.value = value
```

This is slightly different from the code you've posted, where you have `x[a][b][c]`, this requires `x[a, b, c]`.

```
>>> d = PersistentDictView(session)
>>> d['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] = 5
>>> d['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
5
>>> d['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] += 5
>>> session.commit()
>>> d['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
10
```

If you really need your nesting for some reason, you could get that behavior with only a bit more work, but it would require a little more effort.  Additionally, this totally punts on transaction management, notice the explicit `session.commit()` above.